# Incorrect values from common block

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

How can I create a link between routine and sub-program using Fortran?

```
Program Example

    common a,b,c,d,e
    print*,"Enter a"
          read*,a
    print*,"Enter coefficient of x in f1(x)"
          read*,b
    print*,"Enter intercept in f1(x)"
          read*,c
    print*,"Enter coefficient of x in f2(x)"
          read*,d
    print*,"Enter intercept in f2(x)"
          read*,e

    Print*,f1(2.),f2(3.)
    pause
    end
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function f1(x)
    common a,b,c
    f1=a*x**2+b*x+c
    return
    end
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function f2(y)
    common d,e
    f2=d*y+e
    return
    end
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

this was an example.
when I print the f1(2.) and f2(3.) I get true result for the first one and false results for the second one.

Answer (score 5):

There are two very different questions in your post.

1. How do we share data between subprograms? In modern Fortran use modules. We have many questions and answers about that. Common blocks are obsolete (and since Fortran 2018 officially obsolescent - Thanks @steve).
2. Why are the results using `common` incorrect?

You are using an unnamed common block. In comon blocks the variable names are irrelevant. They can differ arbitrarily between compilation units (main program, subprograms). The order is important.

Therefore your

```
common d,e
```

is the same as doing

```
common a,b
```

To get access to the fifth element of the common block you must have all five variables

```
common a,b,c,d,e
```

(or as francescalus points out, one has to reference the right numerical storage unit. Ome could also have one array instead.)

Finally, I would like the stress the importance of `implicit none`. You should really use it.

Comment: Thank you !  I got the point. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As a minor point, it isn't necessary to have "all five variables", just to have five numeric storage units accessible.

Comment: From Fortran 2018, _B.3 Obsolescent features: ...  (10) COMMON and EQUIVALENCE statements, and the block data program unit ­ see B.3.11._